# K2 workflow -Unable to view SmartObjects

Tags: k2

in K2 designer, I have created new categories for K2 Learning projects as shown below

[image]

However When I create a new Workflow Item, give in the form, smart objects and folio details, and then navigate to Smart Objects tab in the designer, I do not see my project listed here. Only some of the existing projects seem to be listed. Could you help?

[image]

I am doing a test project as suggested in K2 website
[LeaveRequestApp](https://help.k2.com/onlinetraining/BP1/default.htm#Resources/Projects/LeaveReqBasic/LeaveReqBasicBuildGuide.htm%3FTocPath%3D100BHX%253A%2520Introduction%2520to%2520K2%2520Applications%2520with%2520K2%2520Designer%7CPart%25201%253A%2520K2%2520Application%2520Basics%7CEXERCISE%25201%253A%2520Leave%2520Application%2520(Basic%2520Version)%7C_____2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you create a Smart Object, view and form, make sure you deploy the solution before creating the workflow. Project will be visible for selection after deploying.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Edit your Smartobject, there's an option to check to allow it to be used in workflow.

This option allow you to view the Smartobject from the web-based workflow designer.

Answer (score 1):

After creating the smartobject in the k2 studio ( or if you are using visual studio) you should deploy the project from k2 studio.
If your creating the smartobject using k2 tester utility then you have to select the destination folder where you have to store the smartobject